# Confusing for these pieces of code of interface implementation and calling?

Tags: go, interface

#### Version of Go

- go version go1.11 darwin/amd64

Code 1:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myintf interface {
    GotU()
}

type esc struct {
     i int
}

//func GotU(t esc);
func (e esc)GotU() {
    e.i = 10
}

func TestFunc(it myintf) string {
    it.GotU()
    return  "kk"
}

func main() {

    var test esc
    test.i = 9

    TestFunc(test)

    fmt.Println(test.i)

}
```

Code 2:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myintf interface {
    GotU()
}

type esc struct {
     i int
}

func (e esc)GotU() {
    e.i = 10
}

func TestFunc(it myintf) string {
    it.GotU()
    return  "kk"
}

func main() {

    var test esc
    test.i = 9

    TestFunc(&test)

    fmt.Println(test.i)

}
```

Code 3:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myintf interface {
    GotU()
}

type esc struct {
     i int
}

func (e *esc)GotU() {
    e.i = 10
}

func TestFunc(it myintf) string {
    it.GotU()
    return  "kk"
}

func main() {

    var test esc
    test.i = 9

    TestFunc(test)

    fmt.Println(test.i)

}
```

#### The outputs:

- code 1 output: 9
- code 2 output: 9
- code 3 cannot be compiled due to a type mismatch

---

Since only `func (e esc)GotU()` implemented, why should both pieces of code work and deliver the same result?
It's kind of confusing for me to pass a pointer of struct to that function (TestFunc) to get the same answer.

Comment: Is there an implicit conversion from *esc to interface myintf in Code 2? Curious about this.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets: "The method set of [...] pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T that is, it also contains the method set of T)."

Comment: Thanks.This is the explanation I'm seeking for. Furthermore, I expect the output i will be changed to 10 since a pointer is passed in code 2. Since there is no difference with these outputs, I guess it's better to pass the ```test``` rather than ```&test``` for clearance.

Comment: Version 2 still makes a copy of the thing that the pointer points to. The only thing that matters is the method's type, not how it's called.

Comment: @Zalberth there is a difference. In code 2 the receiver is passed by value while in Code 3 the value will be changed to 10. If you pass address to TestFunc. Checkout my answer and link to working code.

Comment: Yes. I've test those code before posting them out. I just feel wonder why this kind of format (passing a pointer) should be allowed since we cannot change the value (still just change a copy of that struct) in that struct.

Comment: @Zalberth you can change the value by passing a pointer type receiver. And this is just like passing pointer as an argument.

Comment: @Himanshu This would need a new func implementation by passing a pointer type receiver. Is that right? If I don't do that, passing a pointer like the code above makes no difference.

Comment: @Zalberth golang prefers this model to change the value. But one need to be considered that if your file contains a method with pointer type receiver then you should pointer type receivers in every method which is using that struct. There are other paramaters too depends on how large is your struct.

Comment: @Zalberth either you pass pointer type receiver or value type depending if you want to change  the value of struct or not respectively. You need not to create a new method one for value type and other for pointer type just pass pointer type.

Comment: @Himanshu In Code 2, without changing the implementation, if I need change i by calling TestFunc, any suggestion? Minor modification I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181689/discussion-between-himanshu-and-zalberth).

Comment: For record, Go's specification says: If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last code snippet has implemented a method receiver of pointer type. This will consider the situation if you want to modify the value of receiver.

```
func (e *esc) GotU() {
    e.i = 10
}
```

In above case Since you are passing pointer type receiver on a method which is implementing the interface.

```
type myintf interface {
    GotU()
}
```

So you need to pass address of struct in `TestFunc`. This is the reason you are getting type mismatch error, because you are passing variable of `esc` type while your method requires variable of `*esc`.

```
func main() {

    var test esc
    test.i = 9
    TestFunc(&test)
    fmt.Println(test.i)

}
```

Working example on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3qgdl96dkrG)

In Golang there are two ways to pass a method receiver.

```
func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
```

> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
>   these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
>   very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
>   above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
>   method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
>   the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
>   value or a pointer. There are several considerations

First, and most important, does the method need to modify the receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.

Comment: This is true, but unrelated to the question. The question is about pointer vs value receivers satisfying an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the 1st and second version is, that you pass the struct directly in one version and the pointer to the struct in the other version. In this case these programs work the same, as the pointer also includes the all defined funcs on the struct.

But this does not work the other way around. You define the method `GotU` on the pointer receiver. The struct does not know about this func. If you would call

```
TestFunc(&test)
```

in the third program, it would compile but work differently than the other two: The output is: "10"

As the `GotU` is defined on the pointer receiver `test` is passed as reference and the modifications persist. In the other programs `test` is passed as value, i.e. it is copied, the copy is modified in `GotU`. When the func exits, the copy is discarded and the old version is still the same as before.

Comment: Thanks. Since 'pointer also includes the all defined funcs on the struct.', I pass a pointer of that struct in Code 2, should the value of i will be changed after calling the TestFunc? But the this results in the same output as I pass just the struct in Code 1.

Comment: The reason is, that the struct is the receiver, not the pointer. This way you will know what happens when you look at the func definition.